# Can fail2ban detect and block IP-ranges?

Tags: fail2ban

Every day I get hundreds of this lines in my mail.log:

```
Apr 28 11:10:28 servername amavis[30077]: (30077-08) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.16] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: F/spam-FaGlty0PIZMS.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: FaGlty0PIZMS, Hits: 7.544, size: 5136, 7444 ms
Apr 28 11:44:53 servername amavis[30074]: (30074-10) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.25] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: H/spam-H4sMG6EC6q-I.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: H4sMG6EC6q-I, Hits: 12.405, size: 5209, 3816 ms
Apr 28 11:45:53 servername amavis[30077]: (30077-10) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.30] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: q/spam-qNkRyAnBW5ul.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: qNkRyAnBW5ul, Hits: 12.405, size: 5217, 4456 ms
Apr 28 12:05:22 servername amavis[30074]: (30074-12) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.11] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: z/spam-zaKH80IIImbj.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: zaKH80IIImbj, Hits: 11.155, size: 5163, 6837 ms
Apr 28 12:06:41 servername amavis[30074]: (30074-13) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.40] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: j/spam-jgw8hoOtyeSf.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: jgw8hoOtyeSf, Hits: 9.546, size: 4749, 3844 ms
Apr 28 12:07:50 servername amavis[30077]: (30077-13) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.95] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: w/spam-wYu7sNla0_BX.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: wYu7sNla0_BX, Hits: 8.87, size: 4729, 3889 ms
Apr 28 12:58:32 servername amavis[30077]: (30077-16) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.46] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: 5/spam-52iE_rnYAkaF.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: 52iE_rnYAkaF, Hits: 19.628, size: 5032, 7830 ms
Apr 28 13:39:12 servername amavis[30077]: (30077-20) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.62] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: 8/spam-8zKenB5I3mjS.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: 8zKenB5I3mjS, Hits: 11.211, size: 5106, 3928 ms
Apr 28 14:22:34 servername amavis[14260]: (14260-04) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.64] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: S/spam-SLdyUkN0XFpi.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: SLdyUkN0XFpi, Hits: 12.405, size: 5146, 3869 ms
Apr 28 14:58:44 servername amavis[14260]: (14260-06) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.47] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: M/spam-MEimd4Bg1bE3.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: MEimd4Bg1bE3, Hits: 11.231, size: 5064, 3838 ms
Apr 28 15:16:17 servername amavis[15052]: (15052-08) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.91] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: M/spam-MVHz2AB6fJWo.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: MVHz2AB6fJWo, Hits: 10.805, size: 5071, 3764 ms
Apr 28 15:16:38 servername amavis[14260]: (14260-09) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.95] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: P/spam-P_vgm1aE0UvA.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: P_vgm1aE0UvA, Hits: 9.555, si 6.694, size: 5656, 2536 ms
Apr 28 15:57:55 servername amavis[14260]: (14260-15) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.108.104] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: 8/spam-8hnRkMDQmj4E.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: 8hnRkMDQmj4E, Hits: 9its: 7.772, size: 8343, 6229 ms
Apr 28 16:36:12 servername amavis[14260]: (14260-20) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedInbound,Quarantined}, [185.140.110.64] <xxx@yyy.com> -> <aaa@bbb.com>, quarantine: J/spam-JAzp8lAdYrqB.gz, Message-ID: <foobar@bla.com>, mail_id: JAzp8lAdYrqB, Hits: 18.228, size: 4938, 4849 ms
```

As you can see, the mails come from different, but similar IPs. In this example from 185.140.110.xxx and 185.140.108.xxx (Or 185.140.110.0/24 and 185.140.108.0/24 in netmask-syntax).

Fail2ban is good in identifying log-lines from identical IP-addresses, but here we have all different addresses, but all from some few small ranges.

Is there a way to tell fail2ban, not to look on identical IP-addresses, but on ranges?

I want fail2ban to block all IPs from 185.140.110.0 to 185.140.110.255 as soon as it detects 3 lines with IP-addresses in this range within a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Fail2ban doesn't have neat functionality to automatically detect and block IP-ranges. It is possible to do, though, using a recent version of fail2ban (I use v0.11), some simple fail2ban scripts and a small, pure python3 script.

Note: The question refers to IP-ranges (which I'll refer to as CIDR blocks, because I find the CIDR notation easy to use in nftables). This is a difficult thing, because we don't know how large a block of addresses the attacker controls. It might even be that the attacker by chance controls a handful of addresses from the same block, with the in-between addresses being legitimate.

### Step 1. Get CIDR of hosts

The log files that fail2ban monitors typically show hosts (e.g. 127.0.0.1) instead of CIDR blocks (127.0.0.0/24) or IP ranges (127.0.0.0 - 127.0.0.255).

A solution could be to first assume a small CIDR block and then grow it as logs report more misbehaving hosts. Obviously it should only grow the CIDR, if those hosts are from adjacent addresses. But this is complex and legitimate addresses might get caught up regardless of the sophistication of the algorithm.

Instead, we can also simply lookup the CIDR in whois. This incurs some latency for the whois lookup, and generates some traffic. But the script that parses whois, can just write the CIDR to syslog, which can the be caught by fail2ban again.

Note: don't forget to hook this script into the actionban of your preferred action.d/lorem-ipsum.conf script. **Be aware that if its maxretry > 1, then you will not catch CIDR blocks where hosts only fail once!**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, subprocess, ipaddress, syslog

def narrowest_cidr(cidrA, cidrB):
    _ip, subA = cidrA.split('/')
    _ip, subB = cidrB.split('/')

    if int(subA) > int(subB):
        return cidrA
    else:
        return cidrB

bad_ip = sys.argv[1]
cidrs = []
inetnums = []
ret = None

whois = subprocess.run(['whois', bad_ip], text=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)

for line in whois.stdout.split('\n'):
    if 'CIDR:' in line:
        cidrs.append(line.replace('CIDR:', '').strip())
    if 'inetnum:' in line:
        inetnums.append(line.replace('inetnum:', '').strip())

if len(cidrs) >= 1:
    if len(cidrs) == 1:
        cidr = cidrs[0]
    else:
        cidr = narrowest_cidr(cidrs[0], cidrs[-1])
elif len(inetnums) > 0:
    if len(inetnums) == 1:
        inetnum = inetnums[0]
        startip, endip = inetnum.split(' - ')
        cidrs = [ipaddr for ipaddr in ipaddress.summarize_address_range(ipaddress.IPv4Address(startip), ipaddress.IPv4Address(endip))]
        if len(cidrs) == 1:
            cidr = cidrs[0]
        else:
            cidr = narrowest_cidr(cidrs[0], cidrs[-1])
else:
    cidr = "no CIDR found"

syslog.openlog(ident="suspectrange")
syslog.syslog("{} has CIDR {}".format(bad_ip, cidr))
```

### Step 2. Figure out when to block a CIDR

If we had the dynamic CIDR determination this might get a little elaborate, as we'd have to change what we're banning. But with the whois lookup we can simply ban the CIDR block we found, based on a maxretry and findtime that we deem appropriate. Here's the jail I use:

```
[fail2ban-cidr-recidive]
filter = fail2ban-cidr-recidive
action = nftables-common[name=BADRANGE]
logpath = /var/log/everything/current

#5 bans in 12hrs is 48hr ban
maxretry = 5
findtime = 12h
bantime = 2d
```

And accompanying filter

```
[Definition]

failregex = \[suspectrange\] .* has CIDR <SUBNET>
```

### Step 3. Actually block the CIDR

As you may have noticed, I use action.d/nft-common.conf. nftables allows blocking CIDR blocks instead of single hosts. This requires a small change to the first line of the actionstart part of the action script:

```
actionstart = nft add set netdev f2b <set_name> \{ type ipv4_addr\; \}
```

Should be modified to:

```
actionstart = nft add set netdev f2b <set_name> \{ type ipv4_addr\; flags interval\; \}
```